# struts2 - optiontransferselect - pass list of integers to the action

Tags: struts2

I have an optiontransferselect in a form but i dont know how to get the selected items in the rightlist back in my action.

I need to get a list with all the visited countries' ids. i tried in my action List (Integer) countriesVisitedId; but it returns nullPointerException. then i tried Integer id but it returns null.

this is what i have:

s:optiontransferselect

```
              label="Select visited countries"
              name="countriesNotVisitedId"
              leftTitle="Not visited countries"
              rightTitle="Visited Countries"
              list="%{countriesNotVisited}"
              listKey="id"
              listValue="name"
              headerKey="countryNotVisitedId"
              headerValue="--- Please Select ---"

              doubleName="countriesVisitedId"
              doubleList="%{countriesVisited}"
              doubleHeaderKey="countryVisitedId"
              doubleHeaderValue="--- Please Select ---"
              doubleListKey="id"
              doubleListValue="name" />
```

how can I get the list with the Integers ids of the visited countries in my action?

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I tried, it works fine.

Step 1: JSP to select the country from the left hand side into right hand.

```
<s:optiontransferselect 
 label="Favourite Characters"
 name="leftSide"
 id="left"
 leftTitle="Left Title"
 rightTitle="Right Title"
 list="%{countriesNotVisited)"
 multiple="true"
 headerKey="headerKey"     
 doubleList="{}"
 doubleId="right"
 doubleName="rightSide"
 doubleHeaderKey="doubleHeaderKey"
 doubleMultiple="true" />
```

Step 2: Javascript code to auto select all data from the right hand side.

```
 function selectall()
 {
 var list = document.getElementById("right");
 for (var i = 0; i < list.options.length; i++) 
   {
    alert(list.options[i].value)
    list.options[i].selected = true;
   }
 var form = document.getElementById("right");
 form.submit();
      return true;

}
```

Step 3: call this function on submit, from the JSP side.

```
<s:submit id="submitid" value="Submit" action="insert" onclick="selectall()"/>
```

Step 4: In the action, make the getters and setters of object names of the left and right sides take strings and not string arrays.

```
private String leftSide;
private String rightSide;

public String getLeftSide() {
    return leftSide;
}

public String getRightSide() {
    return rightSide;
}

public void setRightSide(String rightSide) {
    this.rightSide = rightSide;
}

public void setLeftSide(String leftSide) {
    this.leftSide = leftSide;
}
```

Now if you try to print a value in the action, you will get values:

```
System.out.println("right side list " + ad.getRightSide());
```

Answer (score 1):

I was banging my head on the wall wondering what I was doing wrong. It is pretty simple

doubleName="fields" is the tag field that is returned

public void setFields(String fields) { this is what needs to be in your action class.

The thing that I didn't realise is the elements need to be selected in order to be sent back. Or simple use ajax with  in your header

Answer (score 0):

In your action:

```
 public void setCountriesVisitedId(String[] countriesVisitedId) {
    this.countriesVisitedId = countriesVisitedId;
 }
```